# Multiple Name Pattern and Parameter definition

Tags: azure-policy

I have a policy that I am putting in place to monitor the naming convention of resources.  We have a specific guideline that provides some variation, and I think I've captured it accurately.

Using this as a sample

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/allow-multiple-name-patterns

I've come up with the following I think would work. Problem is when I go to deploy it, Azure Policy api says I have parameters defined, but they're not used, and clearly they are.  Looking for assistance on creating a multiple name pattern using parameters, and if this is possible.

````
    "properties": {
        "displayName": "Match multiple name patterns.",
        "description": "Allows one of multiple naming patterns for resources.",
        "mode": "Indexed",
        "parameters": {
            "buName": {
               "type": "String",
               "metadata": {
                  "description": "Abbreviated Business Unit / i.e. USNR, SHSD, MAXD"
               }
            },
            "regionShortCode": {
               "type": "String",
               "metadata": {
                  "description": "Shortcode for the region / i.e. CUS, NCU, EUS"
               }
            },
            "environmentShortCode": {
                "type": "String",
                "metadata": {
                   "description": "Environment code / i.e. D (dev), U (uat), P (prod)"
                }
             }
         },
        "policyRule": {
            "if": {
                "allOf": [
                    {
                        "not": {
                            "field": "name",
                            "match": "[parameters('buName')]-[parameters('regionShortCode')]-[parameters('environmentShortCode')]-???-###"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "not": {
                            "field": "name",
                            "match": "[parameters('buName')]-[parameters('regionShortCode')]-[parameters('environmentShortCode')]-???"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "not": {
                            "field": "name",
                            "match": "[parameters('regionShortCode')]???[parameters('environmentShortCode')]##"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "not": {
                            "field": "name",
                            "match": "[parameters('regionShortCode')]???[parameters('environmentShortCode')]###"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            "then": {
                "effect": "audit"
            }
        }
    }
} ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only supposed to have the brackets once and concat everything together. Try using this method: [concat(parameters('buName'), '-', parameters('regionShortCode'), '-', parameters('environmentShortCode'), '-???-###')]

Comment: Thank you Kemley!  That did it, I'm not sure why I didn't think of that.  Extremely thankful for the second set of eyes on this.

Answer (score 0):

The error that you are getting is it at assignment time?

Also, for the parameters you are using? Is there a defined list of which users must use? If its just a pattern convention like for bus its a 4 letter name then you should use the wildcard.

Remember that at assignment time you must specify each parameter.

Comment: It's not at assignment time, I'm creating a definition, and during the definition creation, it tells me that I've declared parameters but never used them.  Which if you look at the rule set is not the case.  The goal is that during assignment time, the operator will fill in the appropriate values to the parameters.  

Again the error comes during the definition of the policy within the Azure portal.

Comment: Also, I don't want to use the wildcard for specific portions of the name.  There are sections of the name that can be wildcard specified and numeric, but there are sections that are not which is why I have the parameters.