# Checking that old and new ressources are configured with a tag with specific case

Tags: azure, azure-policy

Hello community ‍♂️!

I'm configuring an Azure Policy to check presence of a tag on new and old ressources.

Checking the presence only was quite easy:

```
 policy_rule = <<RULE
  {
    "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
            },
            {
              "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('TagName'), ']')]",
              "exists": "false"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
        }
  }
  RULE
```

With following parameters:

```
parameters = <<PARAMETERS
 {
        "tagName": {
          "type": "String",
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Tag Name",
            "description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"
          }
        },
        "effect": {
          "type": "String",
          "defaultValue": "Audit",
          "allowedValues": [
            "Audit",
            "Deny",
            "Disabled"
          ],
          "metadata": {
            "displayName": "Effect",
            "description": "The effect determines what happens when the policy rule is evaluated to match"
          }
        }
  }
PARAMETERS
```

But *now I want that the policy rule also **checks the case of the tagName** parameters*.

Ex: guess expected tagName is `RigorousMakeMeHappy`. Then, I want that ressources be configured with `RigorousMakeMeHappy` but **not** with `rigorousmakemehappy` or `rigorousMakeMeHappy` or `RIGOROUSMAKEMEHAPPY` etc.

And I struggled two days w/o success.

I tried, among others things, the following:

```
  policy_rule = <<RULE
  {
    "if": {
          "anyOf": [
            {
            "field": "tags",
            "match": "[parameters('tagName')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
        }
  }
  RULE
```

I tried to achieve with following documentations:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/samples/pattern-fields
- [Multiple Name Pattern and Parameter definition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59653416/multiple-name-pattern-and-parameter-definition)
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/governance/policy/concepts/definition-structure

Thanks for your precious help !

EDIT: @SiddheshDesai

I should be more specific, I want **ONLY** the Key matching case sensitive my pattern:

With this code:

```
  policy_rule = <<RULE
  {
    "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
            "not": {
               "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",
              "match": "[parameters('tagName')]"
             }
            },
             {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
        }
  }
```

It's not working:

[Create VM with Tag RigorousMakeMeHappy and value qsdsqfsdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A56yn.png)

And result is:

[Validation not OK because we are trying to match the value of the KV pair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XPUgr.png)

If I change the tag in this way:

[Create VM with Tag RigorousMakeMeHappy and value RigorousMakeMeHappy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KX99T.png)

Result is:

[Validation OK because we are matching the value of the KV pair](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81Sqw.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- EDIT: I improved first solution to fix case where you have the pattenr `RigorousMakesMeHappywhateveryouaddtomatchingpattern`

@SiddheshDesai: I've found the answer (or one of... but honestly I think it's the only one ) and, again, thanks for your time!

Here is the code:

```
policy_rule = <<RULE
  {
    "if": {
          "allOf": [
            {
              "field": "type",
              "equals": "Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines"
            },
            {
            "anyOf": [
              {
                 "value": "[contains(string(field('tags')),parameters('backupTagName'))]",
                 "notMatch": "True" 
              },
              {
                 "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('backupTagName'), ']')]",
                 "exists": "false"
              }
            ]
            }
          ]
        },
        "then": {
          "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
        }
  }
  RULE
```

Then, if you `tagName` is **RigorousMakesMeHappy** and whatever the tagValue is you will be compliant or not with:

- RigorousMakesMeHappy: ✅ (compliant)
- RigorousMakesMeHappywhateveryouaddtomatchingpattern:❌ (not compliant)
- rigorousMakesMeHappy: ❌
- RigorousMakesMeHapPY: ❌
- qsdfqsdfqsfd: ❌
- yougettheidea: ❌

Answer (score 0):

I tried below Azure Policy definition to audit the Resources in the Azure subscription if the  **tag name** **RigorousMakeMeHappy** is not present it will be marked as a **non-compliant** resource with case sensitivity:-

Policy definition:-

```json
{

"mode": "All",

"policyRule": {

"if": {

"allOf": [

{

"field": "type",

"equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"

},

{

"not": {

"field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tagName'), ']')]",

"match": "[parameters('tagName')]"

}

}

]

},

"then": {

"effect": "[parameters('effect')]"

}

},
"parameters": {

"tagName": {

"type": "String",

"metadata": {

"displayName": "Tag Name",

"description": "Name of the tag, such as 'environment'"

},

"defaultValue": "RigorousMakeMeHappy"

},

"effect": {

"type": "String",

"metadata": {

"displayName": "Effect",

"description": "The effect determines what happens when the policy rule is evaluated to match"

},

"allowedValues": [

"Audit",

"Deny",

"Disabled"

],

"defaultValue": "Audit"

}

}

}
```

**Output:-**

**animalrg, girraferg, siliconrg098  and valleyrg resource group does not contain**
**RigorousMakeMeHappy**  so its marked as **non-compliant**, Refer below:-

[image]

*animalrg tag:-*

[image]

*girraferg tag:-*

[image]

*valleyrg tag:-*

[image]

*siliconrg098 tag:-*

[image]

**Where as siliconrg resource group contains RigorousMakeMeHappy thus its marked as compliant**, Refer below:-

[image]

[image]

Comment: @Greg'ory Match and notmatch will consider the values as case sensitive by default, Thus only tag name with RigorousMakeMeHappy will be compliant

Comment: Thanks @SiddheshDesai!

But I should be more specific!

You solution is great if I want both key **AND** the value having the same pattern:

RigorousMakeMeHappy : RigorousMakeMeHappy  ✅
RigorousMakeMeHappy : qfqsdfqsdfq ❌
qfqsdfqsdfq : RigorousMakeMeHappy ✅

But that's not what I wanted... my bad i was not clear enough 

I want **ONLY** the **key** matching the tagName parameters.
With Microsoft solution I could only test the value of the key/value pair...

Comment: @Greg'ory The above code matches only key that is tag name, I have added value just for an example

Comment: Are you sure @SiddheshDesai? I tried with `RigorousMakeMeHappy : qfqsdfqsdfq` and it's not working...

Comment: Can you try this definition? {
  "mode": "All",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "field": "type",
          "equals": "Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups"
        },
        {
          "not": {
            "field": "[[for(tagKey, tagValue) in tags]:if(equals(tagKey, parameters('tagName')), bool('true'), bool('false'))]",
            "match": "[parameters('tagName')]"
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]"
    }
  },

Comment: Thanks for your time @SiddheshDai, but this one is not working too...

Comment: @SiddheshDai, Do you mind to show me where you find documentation to use a `For` inside policy rule?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure @SiddheshDesai? I tried with RigorousMakeMeHappy : qfqsdfqsdfq and it's not working...>> Is it considering it as non-compliant?